# Populate one custom adapter with two array list in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two arraylist and I want to display the data in both list in the same recyclerview. My code looks like this.

My adapter

```
class NotificationAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationViewHolder> {
//..
List<Notification> notifList = new ArrayList<>();
List<AcceptedInvitation> acceptedInvitations = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public NotificationAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void addNotification(Notification notification){
    notifList.add(notification);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    notifyItemInserted(notifList.size());
}

public void addAcceptedInvitation(AcceptedInvitation invitation){
    acceptedInvitations.add(invitation);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    notifyItemInserted(acceptedInvitations.size());
}

@Override
public NotificationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_notifications, parent, false);

    NotificationViewHolder holder = new NotificationViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NotificationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String user1= null;
    String user2= null;

    if(position < notifList.size()){

        user1= notifList.get(position).getUserName();

    }else {
        user2= acceptedInvitations.get(position).getUserName();

    }


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notifList.size() + acceptedInvitations.size();
}
}
```

RecyclerView ViewHolder

```
public class NotificationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
//..  
TextView userName;

public NotificationViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);   
}
}
```

I have an error in onBindViewHolder() part. I'm using Firebase in retrieving the data by the way.

Main Activity(loadData() is called when the activity starts)

```
 public void loadData(){
    //..
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("users").child(key).child("invitations");

    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Notification notification = dataSnapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
            adapter.addNotification(notification);
       }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    DatabaseReference invitationRef = database.getReference().child("users").child(key).child("acceptedInvitations");
    invitationRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            AcceptedInvitation acceptedInvitation = dataSnapshot.getValue(AcceptedInvitation.class);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            adapter.addAcceptedInvitation(acceptedInvitation);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I can already retrieve the data from invitations and acceptedInvitations json-array, but i have an error when I tried to populate the data from the acceptedInvitations, basically when I call "addAcceptedInvitation(acceptedInvitation)".
Error.

> threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a81c80)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the highest risk on error is in this line `user2= acceptedInvitations.get(position).getUserName();` and this line probably get called before your `acceptedInvitations` have value on `position`. Please edit your question mentioning code you call `addNotification` and `addAcceptedInvitation` and if their data from Firebase, please provide coded where you call Firebase

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already edited my question.

Comment: Try replacing `else` in `if(position < notifList.size()){ ... } else { .. }` with `.. } else if (position < acceptedInvitations.size()) { ... }`. It should make your error disappear. (and mention me when you reply me :D)

Comment: The error disappeared but the data is not populated in the recyclerview. @koceeng

Comment: This is the error. threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a81c80) @JuanCruzSoler. I've edited my question above.

Comment: Your code logic is so confusing. So you want your array result like this? notif1, notif2, notif3, inv1, inv2, inv3?

Comment: Yes, just like that @koceeng

Comment: Your solution worked. Thank you so much sir. God Bless you :D @koceeng

Comment: Can you mark it as accepted so that if others have this same problem, they know that my answer is working :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to combine the `Notification` data and `AcceptedInvitation` data. Please note that when you call two Firebase Database call, the second one will be executed after the first one is finished. So it is okay to use this code below (because if not, this code is risky).

First, remove `notifyItemInserted()` inside `addNotification` and `addAcceptedInvitation` as it is no use if it's called directly after `notifyDataSetChanged()`. But if you prefer keeping `notifyItemInserted()` and removing `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it will be more complicated.

Then lets point out what went wrong. When you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, your adapter will refresh all of its item. In your `getItemCount()`, you mention that your adapter have `(notifList.size() + acceptedInvitations.size())`. So if you have 3 `notifList` and 2 `acceptedInvitations`, your adapter will refresh from its first value to (3+2) fifth value.

Knowing that, the `onBindViewHolder` will be called with `position` value from 0 to 4 (0 is first, 4 is fifth). Look at the code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NotificationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    if(position < notifList.size()){
        user1 = notifList.get(position).getUserName();

    } else {
        user2 = acceptedInvitations.get(position).getUserName();
    }
}
```

Notice that when `position` is 0 or 1 or 2, it is fine because its executing `notifList.get(position)` and `notifList` on those index is exist. But when `position` is 3, its executing `acceptedInvitations.get(position)` that will triger error because `acceptedInvitations` only have value on index 0 and 1 not in 3

After understanding that, your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NotificationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    if(position < notifList.size()){
        user1 = notifList.get(position).getUserName();

    } else {
        user2 = acceptedInvitations.get(position - notifList.size()).getUserName();
    }
}
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: I encountered a case which I will have to populate the adapter with more than two list. I have tried to add this code **user2 = acceptedInvitations.get(position - listA.size() + listB.size()).getUserName();** But it wont work. I have 3 lists by the way.

Comment: if you have 3 list, of course the code will be different. I've included the logic why I come up with that code in my answer. If you read it carefully and understand it AND if your code logic is still the same then `user2 = acceptedInvitations.get(position - listA.size() + listB.size() + listC.size()).getUserName();` will work